# How to make an object properly hashable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + str(self.age)

    def __hash__(self):
        print(hash(str(self)))
        return hash(str(self))

heroes = set()

heroes.add(Hero('Zina Portnova', 16)) # gets hash -8926039986155829407
print(len(heroes)) # gets 1

heroes.add(Hero('Lara Miheenko', 17)) # gets hash -2822451113328084695
print(len(heroes)) # gets 2

heroes.add(Hero('Zina Portnova', 16)) # gets hash -8926039986155829407
print(len(heroes)) # gets 3! WHY?
```

Why is this happening?
The 1st and the 3rd object have same content and same hash but `len()` tells about 3 unique objects?

Comment: Not sure, but your probably need `__eq__` or `__cmp__`: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable

Comment: That aside, this isn’t the best hash function (because you’re not hashing a general string, one of the string components has much lower entropy because it’s known to consist of digits). For a trivial but pretty effective fix, take the hash values of the objects separately and xor them. For more magic, add them scaled by a prime number constant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: There's an implied assumption in your comment – specifically that a "good" hash is needed for the set to perform well.  This is not the case with Python's `set` implementation; see [this comment from the Python sources](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/26e2ee402a0b/Objects/dictobject.c#l113) for further explanations.

Comment: @Sven I somewhat disagree. First, this is a CPython implementation detail, not guaranteed by Python. Second, this still assumes high entropy in the lower bits (*and* to some extent later in the higher bits, for collision). You still need good randomness, only not over the whole number range. Third, the comment, while detailed, is somewhat murky on the theory side. I’m not very confident in this far-from-rigorous analysis. I want a rigorous, peer-reviewed study on that, not some hand-waving.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The hash function should actually be implemented as `hash((self.name, self.age))`, deferring the details to the tuple hash algorithm of the Python implementation, which is hopefully optimised to work well with the `set` and `dict` implementations.  And I agree that the linked comment is not a rigorous analysis. I find it interesting anyway; extensive and thorough benchmarking, as has been [performed for the CPython `dict` implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/26e2ee402a0b/Objects/dictnotes.txt), might lead to better performance in practice than a rigorous analysis.

Comment: @Sven I agree with your suggestion to defer the hashing to the tuple type, didn’t think of that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry for being so late to the party, but I find the discussion very intriguing as it contradicts my naive understanding of hash functions. I assume by good you mean in terms of distribution. Why is str(number) be decremental for that? The operation doesn't loose entropy for integers, right? So if the hash function itself is good as in seemingly "randomly" mapping input symbols to output symbols, where have I lost anything? Of course the tuple solution is cleaner and hopefully more efficient.

Comment: @Zulan Under perfect condition (= a hash that distributes the input perfectly uniformly) you’re right, and no entropy is lost. However, these perfect conditions are entirely theoretical. In practice, a hash function can only approximate them (unless your input is bounded, in which case you can compute a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)). And that’s why hashing using separate functions for separate input domains, and then combining those hashes, yields better distributions.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You also need to define `__eq__()` in a compatible way with [`__hash__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) – otherwise, equality will be based on object identity.

On Python 2, it is recommended you also define `__ne__` to make `!=` consistent with `==`. On Python 3, the default `__ne__` implementation will delegate to `__eq__` for you.

Comment: Indeed, after checking if the hashes are equal, the `dict`/`set` must also check for actual equality in case of hash collision.

Comment: @user2357112 Definig `__ne__` not required to make a type hashable, right?  It may be good idea to define it, since otherwise `!=` will have rather weird semantics, but if all you want to do is using the type in a set or dictionary, you don't really need it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Technically, sets and dicts don't use `!=` anywhere, but actually relying on that is a recipe for nasty bugs. Even if sets don't use `!=`, someone's probably gonna. You can reword it if you want, but I think the answer should definitely mention `__ne__`; the spirit of the question definitely seems more "how do I do things *right*" than "what is the bare minimum needed to get this code snippet to produce the expected output".

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not sure I fully agree; it really depends on the scope of what you are working on.  And the fact that set and dict don't use `!=` isn't an accident, but documented and guaranteed behaviour.  The Python 2 glossary also defines hashable as basically "having `__hash__ and (__eq__ or __cmp__)`" without any mention of `__ne__`.  Anyway, I agree that it never hurts to define it, and slightly modified the wording.

Comment: In order for a `set.add(x)` to include `x` into the set, where `x` is a user-defined type, both `hash(x)` must return a unique integer (i.e., one that is not already seen when hash() is called on each of the objects already in  a set) AND `__eq__(self,x)` must be false. In other words, if two instances hash to the same value OR is equal by `__eq__` definition, then it is not included from the set when you call `set.add(x)`. Is this correct?

Comment: @MinhTran No, that's not correct.  You are entirely allowed to have hash collisions between objects that are different, and you can add still add both of them to the set.  You can try this by adding the integers `-1` and `-2` to a set.  They both hash to `-2`, but obviously don't compare equal.

Answer (score 33):

Here  is the the entire code :

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + str(self.age)

    def __hash__(self):
        print(hash(str(self)))
        return hash(str(self))

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.name == other.name and self.age== other.age



heroes = set()
heroes.add(Hero('Zina Portnova', 16)) # gets hash -8926039986155829407
print(len(heroes)) # gets 1

heroes.add(Hero('Lara Miheenko', 17)) # gets hash -2822451113328084695
print(len(heroes)) # gets 2

heroes.add(Hero('Zina Portnova', 16)) # gets hash -8926039986155829407
print(len(heroes)) # gets 2
```

The function recognises the `__eq__` and as such the len is 2.

Answer (score 11):

[The Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) might be helpful:

> If a class does not define a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either;