# Which data structure to use when implementing graph representation using adjacency list

Tags: python, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I have a graph that is very big about 1,000,000 nodes and many edges. This is what i wanted to know which is the best suited data structure when implementing an adjacency list. Here are the objects that i keep track of

- Edge list
- Node to node connection list

I am coding with python so I used a set(because according to  [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) it has a o(1) average insertion time) for edge list and a dictionary to node to node connection list(by making it completely hashable according to [How to make an object properly hashable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994229/how-to-make-an-object-properly-hashable)). Here is my code

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, name = ""):
        self.__name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__name)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if(type(self) != type(other)):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__name.__lt__(other.__name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if(type(self)) != type(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__name  == other.__name

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, name = "", node1 = None, node2 = None, weight = 0):
        self.__name = name
        self.__firstNode = node1
        self.__secondNode = node2
        self.__weight = weight

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def getFirstNode(self):
        return self.__firstNode

    def getSecondNode(self):
        return self.__secondNode

    def getWeight(self):
        return self.__weight

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if(type(self) != type(other)):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__name.__lt__(other.__name) and self.__firstNode.__lt__(other.__firstNode) and self.__secondNode.__lt__(other.__secondNode) and self.__weight.__lt__(other.__weight)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if(type(self) != type(other)):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__name == other.__name and self.__firstNode == other.__firstNode and self.__secondNode == other.__secondNode and self.__weight == other.__weight

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name + " " + str(self.__firstNode) + " " + str(self.__secondNode) + " " + str(self.__weight)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(hash(self.__name) + hash(self.__firstNode) + hash(self.__secondNode) + hash(self.__weight))

class graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__nodeToNode = {}
        self.__edgeList = set()

    def addEdge(self, edge):
        if(type(edge) != type(Edge())):
            return False

        self.__edgeList.add(edge)
        if(not edge.getFirstNode() in self.__nodeToNode):
            self.__nodeToNode[edge.getFirstNode()] = set()

        self.__nodeToNode[edge.getFirstNode()].add(edge.getSecondNode())
        if(not edge.getSecondNode() in self.__nodeToNode):
            self.__nodeToNode[edge.getSecondNode()] = set()

        self.__nodeToNode[edge.getSecondNode()].add(edge.getSecondNode())
        return True
    def getNodes(self):
        return dict(self.__nodeToNode)
    def getEdges(self):
        return set(self.__edgeList)


import string
import random
import time

grp = graph()
nodes = [None] * 20000
for i in range(20000):
    st = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10))
    node1 = node(st)
    nodes[i] = node1

current = time.time()
for i in range(3000000):
    rdm = random.randint(0, 199)
    rdm2 = random.randint(0, 199)
    st = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10))
    eg = Edge(st, nodes[rdm], nodes[rdm2])
    grp.addEdge(eg)

last = time.time()

print((last - current))

nodes = grp.getNodes()
edges = grp.getEdges()
```

but this code runs very slowly can i make it faster? If so by using what data structure?

Comment: Do you want to code this yourself or are you happy with third party solutions ? If yes, you may want to have a look at the graph database Neo4j (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j) or, alternatively, the python-graph package.

Comment: @Jaco I will check it out but this is for school project I have to code it myself

Comment: Use networkx library. (https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Simple functions to add node, edge and weights exist. Also it's very easy to plot the nodes and edges.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use any libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me introduce you a way to create an adjacency list:

Suppose you have the input like this:

```
4 4
1 2
3 2
4 3
1 4
```

The first line contains 2 numbers `V` and `E`, the next `E` lines defines an edge between two vertices.

You can either create a .txt file and read the input or directly type in via `sys.stdin.read()`:

```
input = sys.stdin.read()
data = list(map(int, input.split()))
n, m = data[0:2]
data = data[2:]
edges = list(zip(data[0:(2 * m):2], data[1:(2 * m):2]))
x, y = data[2 * m:]
adj = [[] for _ in range(n)]
x, y = x - 1, y - 1
for (a, b) in edges:
    adj[a - 1].append(b - 1)
    adj[b - 1].append(a - 1)
```

Let's output the adjacency list `adj`:

```
>>> print(adj)
[[1, 3], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0]]
```

`adj[0]` have two adj nodes: 1 and 3. Meaning the node 1 have two adj nodes: 2 and 4.

And now, if you want a directed, weighted graph, you just need to modify the input like this:

```
4 4
1 2 3 # edge(1, 2) has the weight of 3
3 2 1
4 3 1
1 4 2

input = sys.stdin.read()
data = list(map(int, input.split()))
n, m = data[0:2]
data = data[2:]
edges = list(zip(zip(data[0:(3 * m):3], data[1:(3 * m):3]), data[2:(3 * m):3]))
data = data[3 * m:]
adj = [[] for _ in range(n)]
cost = [[] for _ in range(n)]
for ((a, b), w) in edges:
    adj[a - 1].append(b - 1)
    cost[a - 1].append(w)
```

You store the weight in `cost`, and for example, `cost[0][1]` = 3, `cost[0][3]` = 2.

Hope this helped!