# How to filter objects in list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.6. to create two lists. I want to filter it if all of the instances attribute values are the same.

I wrote this code, but it returns false.
How to filter it?

```
class MyCls:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.x = kwargs.get('x')
        self.y = kwargs.get('y')
        self.z = kwargs.get('z')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self.__dict__))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self.__hash__) == str(other.__hash__)


a = MyCls(x='a', y='b', z='c')
b = MyCls(x='a', y='b', z='c')

ab = [a, b]

print(a is b)
# False
print(a == b)
# False

s = set(ab)
print(s)
# print(2 instances)
```

Comment: the hash of an object should be constant for it's whole lifetime - else some things will break in some unexpected ways (cf https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__: _"If a class defines mutable objects and implements an __eq__() method, it should not implement __hash__(), since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket)."_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering on the premise that you are playing around with `__hash__` and `__eq__` for educational purposes.

I find your hashing and equality methods... weird.

Anyway, the concrete problem with your code is that `__eq__` does not call the `__hash__` method.

You can use

```
return str(self.__hash__()) == str(other.__hash__())
```

in `__eq__` - or better (but still weird)

```
return hash(self) == hash(other)
```

With this adjustment you get

```
>>> hash(a)
>>> 8280333490847949293
>>> hash(b)
>>> 8280333490847949293
>>> a == b
>>> True
```

However, a fundamental flaw with this design is that an instance of `MyClass` will compare equal with any other object that hashes the same by accident.

```
>>> class C:
...:    def __hash__(self):
...:        return 8280333490847949293
...:    
>>> C() == a
>>> True
```

If you want to compare instance attributes, why not compare the instance dicts directly?

Comment: Thanks I understood my mistake. but how to compare instances dicts directly?

Comment: @rootpetit you can access an instance `dict` with `my_object.__dict__` or `vars(my_object)` and compare dictionaries with `==`. Remember that instances of two different classes can still have equal `__dict__` attributes, so you probably also need an `isinstance` check.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to fix `__eq__` to check `isinstance of MyCls` and `return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__` to compare attribute (and remove __hash__).

Comment: @rootpetit you're welcome! If you want to put your objects into a set, they need to be hashable. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994229/how-to-make-an-object-properly-hashable) question.

Comment: I think usecase, and If I use it with set, I implement above class __hash__. Thanks!