# How to compare python object attributes using cython?

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, cython, lookup

I am trying to speed up one python function that compares the ids stored as attribute values of two objects. So my class stores a few values and otherwise looks like this:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

I have a dictionary `Dic_Storage` that has `(room, period)` tuples as keys and objects from the event class as values. My function checks for a certain `event, period` combination whether there is already an event with the same id scheduled in any of the rooms:

```
def check_ids(event, period)
    for room in Dic_Rooms:
        if Dic_Storage[(room, period)].id == event.id:
            return True
    return False
```

So I wanted to try using cython and declare the variables upfront. `event` is an python object, `period` an integer, `room` is a string and the return value is boolean. However, out of the four I could only find integer and boolean in the cython docs: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html

I naively tried something like this without success:

```
cpdef bint check_ids(struct event, int period)
    for room in Dic_Rooms:
        if Dic_Storage[(room, period)].id == event.id:
            return True
    return False
```

Sadly, I have zero C knowledge. Is it even possible to do what I want to do like this? Or do I also somehow need to convert my event class to C code for this function to take it as an argument? Because I am accessing these event objects from multiple modules and functions throughout my code and would prefer to keep them as python objects (also, I would not know how to correctly access them if they are declared as c code). This function just gets called very often and I am looking for a way to reduce its overhead.

Best regards,
Jan

Comment: Why not just implement a `__hash__` magic method and let python deal with it? Then you can use a `set` for look ups. You won't get much better performance with cpython.

Comment: I never used the `__hash__` magic method. I thought using it would result in each event object getting a unique hash value. I would need e.g. three event objects that have the same hash in order to identify whether they belong to the same event. If that's possible I will definitely take a look at that thank you :) Is comparing objects with the hash magic method actually faster than simply comparing attribute values?

Comment: Basically you implement `hash` so that objects you believe should be equal will output the same hash.  In terms of speed it is much faster than what you currently do because currently you look over all rooms to look for duplicates (you use a `for` loop), if you [implement hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994240/8150685) you can use a `set` which does not need a loop you can just say `in`.  It will be plenty fast.  You will need to implement `__eq__` to though.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow, thank you! One last thing: I cannot follow you on how to implement a set in this case. If I understand you correctly, my set would have to consist of all those event objects stored in the dictionary that have any of the (Room, Period) tuples as keys. I don't understand how I can get rid of the for loop, don't I still need it to generate the tuples? Or how can I extract only the events corresponding to all (Room, Period) combinations from that specific period? Thanks again!

Comment: I `set` is just a faster way to check if something exists because it doesn't loop. Look more into hashing and sets and you should be able to see how it will solve your case.