# Pythonic way of ignoring the last element when doing set difference

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

Let's say I have two `set()`s:

```py
a = {('1', '2', '3', 'a'), ('1', '2', '4', 'a'), ('1', '2', '5', 'b')}
b = {('1', '2', '3', 'b'), ('1', '2', '4', 'b'), ('1', '2', '6', 'b')}
```

Now, what I want to do is to find the set difference `b \ a` but ignoring the last element from every tuple. So it's just like doing something like this:

```py
a = {('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '2', '4'), ('1', '2', '5')}
b = {('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '2', '4'), ('1', '2', '6')}

In[1]: b - a
Out[1]: {('1', '2', '6')}
```

Expected output:

`b \ a = {('1', '2', '6', 'b')}`

Is there any obvious / pythonic way of achieving this without having to manually iterate over each set and check against each `tuple[:3]`?

Comment: My initial thought is make them classes, define comparison operator

Comment: subclass `set` and overwrite the difference operation. There is no out-of-the-box solution that I know of and I doubt one exists.

Comment: There ist no "key=..." or something alike (as for sort(..)) for sets. Tuples are immuteables and hashable and are compared based on their hash. Removing one element would void the hash. So No - not possible. If you do not need the value you can create 3-part sets : `aa = { t[:3] for t in a }`

Comment: @AK47 The (set) difference between two sets S and T is written S∖T, and means the set that consists of the elements of S which are not elements of T: x∈S∖T⟺x∈S∧x∉T

Comment: Subclass `tuple` and override the difference operator

Comment: @David Please don’t perform gratuitous edits. Fixing grammar and editing for clarity is fine but your edit performed other, unnecessary changes and even introduced incorrect grammar at some point. Furthermore, you added a “thanks” clause, inclusion of which is actively discouraged on this site.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right, I didn't notice those mistakes, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how you might write your own class to override a tuple's normal hashing
behaviour:

```
a_data = [('1', '2', '3', 'a'), ('1', '2', '4', 'a'), ('1', '2', '5', 'b')]
b_data = [('1', '2', '3', 'b'), ('1', '2', '4', 'b'), ('1', '2', '6', 'b')]

class HashableIgnoresLastElement(tuple):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self[:-1] == other[:-1]

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self[:-1])

a = set(map(HashableIgnoresLastElement, a_data))
b = set(map(HashableIgnoresLastElement, b_data))

print(b - a)
```

with output

```
{('1', '2', '6', 'b')}
```

To modify the way sets of tuples behave, we have to modify the way tuples are hashed.

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=hashable),

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable
>   objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
>   member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.

So in order to make the hashing ignore the last element, we have to overload the dunder methods `__eq__` and `__hash__` appropriately. This doesn't end up being so hard because all we have to do is slice off the last element and then delegate to the appropriate methods of a normal `tuple`.

Further reading:

- [How to make an object properly hashable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994229/how-to-make-an-object-properly-hashable)
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Very neat! Could you also describe a bit how this works? It might be worth for the ones who'll read through this solution.

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex. I've added a short explanation `:)`. Really it's just combining bits and pieces of operator overloading and how hashing works in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach defining `a` and `b` with lists rather than sets, since it seems to me that the most straight forward solution implies indexing `b`:

```
a = [('1', '2', '3', 'a'), ('1', '2', '4', 'a'), ('1', '2', '5', 'b')]
b = [('1', '2', '3', 'b'), ('1', '2', '4', 'b'), ('1', '2', '6', 'b')]

# reconstruct the sets of tuples removing the last elements
a_ = {tuple(t) for *t, _ in a}
b_ = [tuple(t) for *t, _ in b]

# index b based on whether an element in a_
[b[ix] for ix, j in enumerate(b_) if j not in a_]
# [('1', '2', '6', 'b')]
```

Comment: This if I'm not mistaking is O(n), since I do use a set for the lookup. Though I do think Izaak van Dongen's answer is much more elegant @konrad

Comment: You’re entirely right, the use of (and enumeration over) a list threw me off but of course a set difference also needs to iterate over the first set.

Answer (score 1):

Sets work fine. It's your data that doesn't work right. If they look different but they are actually the same, then define a data type which behaves like you want. Then set works great on its own.

```
class thing:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d = a, b, c, d

    def __repr__(self):
        return (str((self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)))

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and self.c == other.c       

a = {thing('1', '2', '3', 'a'), thing('1', '2', '4', 'a'), thing('1', '2', '5', 'b')}
b = {thing('1', '2', '3', 'b'), thing('1', '2', '4', 'b'), thing('1', '2', '6', 'b')}
print (b - a)
```

> {('1', '2', '6', 'b')}

Comment: You defined `__repr__` and `__hash__` in terms of tuples, but not `__eq__`. Wouldn’t it be shorter to use tuples here, too? In fact, you can use slicing here and in `__hash__` to shorten the code further.

Comment: Aye, just subclassing tuple was a big improvement to the question as asked.