# Hash table to find class element?

Tags: python, hash

I have a class for which I want to find an based on attributes, without having to iterate through all the instances. Below is sample code - input is a list of financial transactions, with transaction type and subtype. I want to be able to reference an instance directly based on attributes - e.g. via hash table or the like, but not sure how to do it.

---

```
# Financial transactions
###########################################################################################
class IterTransType(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._allTransTypes)

class TransType(metaclass=IterTransType):
    _allTransTypes = []

    def __init__(self, TransType, TransSubType):
        self._allTransTypes.append(self)

        self.TransType = TransType
        self.TransSubType = TransSubType
        # Below are stats kept for this transction type and subtype combination - same kind of stats as for the filters above
        self.TotalAmt = 0 
        self.NumTrans = 0 
        self.Lowest = 0
        self.Highest = 0


def RecordTransaction(inTransType,inTransSubType,Amount):

    found = False
    for transtype in TransType:
        if ((transtype.TransType == inTransType) and (transtype.TransSubType == inTransSubType)):
            transtype.TotalAmt = transtype.TotalAmt + Amount
            found = True
    # ^^^ would like to find element without having to loop through all instances of the class ^^^

    if (found != True):
        new_trans_type = TransType(inTransType,inTransSubType)
        new_trans_type.TotalAmt = Amount
     
    # end of RecordTransaction



def PlayWithTransactions(csv_file):
    print ('PlayWithTransactions')

    RecordTransaction('Expense_regular','Mortgage',1200)
    RecordTransaction('Expense_regular','Groceries',100)
    RecordTransaction('Expense_one_time','NewSuit',1000)
    RecordTransaction('Income_regular','Paycheck',800)
    RecordTransaction('Expense_regular','Groceries',50)

    print ('Stats:')
    for transtype in TransType:
        print ('Trans type: ' + transtype.TransType + ', subtype: ' + transtype.TransSubType + ", Total Amount: " + str(transtype.TotalAmt))

    # end of PlayWithTransactions
```

---

Output:

```
PlayWithTransactions
Stats:
Trans type: Expense_regular, subtype: Mortgage, Total Amount: 1200
Trans type: Expense_regular, subtype: Groceries, Total Amount: 150
Trans type: Expense_one_time, subtype: NewSuit, Total Amount: 1000
Trans type: Income_regular, subtype: Paycheck, Total Amount: 800
```

Tried to find out how to do hash table, and could not find.

Comment: If you want to store a custom class in a set/map for quick lookups, you will need to define the `__eq()__` and `__hash()__` methods for that class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994229/how-to-make-an-object-properly-hashable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Will give it a shot and report back...

Comment: OK well - that shows how to avoid duplication, but what I really want to do is to be able to directly reference the elements.   E.g. say I want to find out how much I spent on groceries.   The only way I know how to do this is to loop through the iterations like this:  *********   

   for transtype in TransType:
        if (transtype.TransType == 'Expense_regular') and (transtype.TransSubType == 'Groceries'):
            print ('\nAmount spent on groceries: ' + str(transtype.TotalAmt))

(also do not know how to do carriage returns here!)